Flutter web3 ethers is undefined
I used flutter_web3 package .
this is my example code :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web3/flutter_web3.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class WalletController extends GetxController {
  var isConnected = false.obs;
  var currentAddress = ''.obs;
  var isSupported = false.obs;

  bool get isEnabled => ethereum != null;
  int currentChain = -1; //current chain // check if web3 is enable

  void init() {
    debugPrint('Initialize : ${Ethereum.isSupported}');
    if (Ethereum.isSupported) {
      ethereum!.onAccountsChanged((accounts) => clear());
      ethereum!.onChainChanged((chainId) => debugPrint('$chainId'));
      isSupported.value = true;
    }
  }

  Future<void> connect() async {
    debugPrint('Connect called');
    if (Ethereum.isSupported && ethereum != null) {
      try {
        var accounts = await ethereum!.requestAccount();

        if (accounts.isNotEmpty) {
          currentAddress.value = accounts.first;
          currentChain = await ethereum!.getChainId();
          isConnected.value = ethereum!.isConnected();
          debugPrint('Chain ID: $currentChain');
        }
      } on EthereumUserRejected {
        debugPrint('User rejected');
      }
    } else {
      debugPrint('Already Connected');
    }
  }

  Future<void> sendToken() async {
    debugPrint('Send token');
    final gasPrice = await ethereum!.request<BigInt>('eth_gasPrice');
    debugPrint('Gas price ${gasPrice.toString()}');

    var request = TransactionRequest(
      to: '0x3966C5D9512118B98D695921B657A78F93DEA703',
      value: BigInt.from(100000000000),
      gasPrice: gasPrice,
    );
    var tx = await provider!.getSigner().sendTransaction(request);

    debugPrint('$tx');
  }

  void clear() {
    debugPrint('Clear');
    currentAddress.value = '';
    currentChain = -1;
    isConnected.value = false;
  }
}

this is my index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="payment">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>payment</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    const serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <!--Ethers-->
  <script src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.6.4.umd.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  <!--Wallet Connect-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@walletconnect/web3-provider@1.6.5/dist/umd/index.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>

How to fix sendToken() method ?
I always receive :
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dart.global.ethers is undefined

